# How to use JBehave tabular parameters from external resource

Tags: parameters, jbehave, tabular

It's really hard to find a complete solution for JBehave tabular parameter usage from external resource in the internet. So I'm writing this article in a much more descriptive manner with very simple example.

This article describes how to use JBehave tabular parameters using an external data file. Following steps will describe how to use that capability using maven

**Configure pom file as follows.**

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.story</include>
                <include>**/*.table</include>**
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
```

Following line in the pom file will copy the .table files to the class path.

```
<include>**/*.table</include>
```

**Write the story file as follows**

```
Given get price data <price>
When print price unit <unit>

Examples:
com/jbehave/example/sample_data.table
```

**Write the sample_data.table file as follows**

```
|price|unit|
|10|EUR|
|20|USD|
|30|XXX|
```

**Write the step class as follows**

```
public class SampleSteps extends Steps {
@Given("get price data <price>")
public void getPrice(@Named("price") String price){
    System.out.println("Price: " + price);
}

@When("print price unit <unit>")
public void printUnit(@Named("unit") String unit){
    System.out.println("Unit: " + unit);
}
}
```

**Write the scenario class as follow**

```
public class SampleScenario extends JUnitStories {

@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass()))
            .useParameterConverters(new ParameterConverters().addConverters(new ParameterConverters.ExamplesTableConverter(new ExamplesTableFactory(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())))))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(new StoryReporterBuilder().withDefaultFormats().withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.HTML));
}

@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
    ArrayList<Steps> stepFileList = new ArrayList<Steps>();
    stepFileList.add(new SampleSteps());

    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), stepFileList);
}

@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    return new StoryFinder().
            findPaths(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(
                            this.getClass()),
                    Arrays.asList("**/sample_story.story"),
                    Arrays.asList(""));    }

@Override
@org.testng.annotations.Test
public void run() throws Throwable {
    super.run();
}
}
```

Bellow line in the scenario class will add the configuration to support external table source from the class path.

```
 useParameterConverters(new ParameterConverters().addConverters(new ParameterConverters.ExamplesTableConverter(new ExamplesTableFactory(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())))))
```

**Project structure will looks like**

[Sample project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY0ZJ.png)

Hope this is much descriptive.

Comment: Can we use csv file instead of . table

Comment: You can implement your own mechanism to read CSV within your step definition